# Java Enum with constructor. Best way to get value by constructor argument

Tags: java

Suppose I have the enum below:

```
public enum RockPaperScissors {
    R("Rock"),
    P("Paper"),
    S("Scissors");

    private final String fullName;

    RockPaperScissors(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public static RockPaperScissors getInstanceByFullName(String fullName) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
                .filter(value -> value.getFullName().equals(fullName))
                .findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No such value in the enum"));
    }
}
```

I want both 
`RockPaperScissors.valueOf("R")` and 
`RockPaperScissors.getInstanceByFullName("Paper")` to work because I call them  by different data providers.

Is there any better alternative to the `getInstanceByFullName` method that I have written?

Edit: My question was whether the Java enum API provides some alternative methods, which apparently it does not. As ernest_k suggested, I improved the `getInstanceByFullName` method.

Comment: This is the typical way to do it. But your implementation can be improved by using a map (and you don't have to stream twice. You can use `findFirst` and `orElseThrow`)

Comment: Well, still I would recommend to rename `R`, `P` and `S` to `ROCK`, `PAPER` and `SCISSORS` respectively.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution would probably be to maintain a static `Map<String, RockPaperScissors>` in the enum:

```java
public enum RockPaperScissors {
    R ("Rock"),
    P ("Paper"),
    S ("Scissors");

    private static final Map<String, RockPaperScissors> byFullName = new HashMap<>();
    private final String fullName;

    RockPaperScissors(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        byFullName.put(fullName, this);
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public static RockPaperScissors getInstanceByFullName(String fullName) {
        return byFullName.get(fullName);
    }
}
```

Essentially, you just precompute a Map as the enum class is loaded to allow for quick lookups by the full names.

(Whether or not it's actually faster than looping over all the values depends on the size of the enum, though. With just three elements, looping might very well be faster.)

Comment: Yeah, this one looks like it would be faster than mine. My question was mainly focused on whether the enum API provides some easy way to do it without having to implement it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do with just one stream operation:

```
   public static RockPaperScissors getInstanceByFullName(String fullName) {
        return Arrays.stream(values())
              .filter(rockPaperScissors -> rockPaperScissors.getFullName().equals(fullName))
              .findFirst()
              .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No such value in the enum"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it and not `stream` it twice, e.g.:

```
public static RockPaperScissors getInstanceByFullName(String fullName) {
    for(RockPaperScissors element : values()) {
        if(element.fullName.equals(fullName)) {
            return element;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such value in the enum");
}
```